# Java program to read/write file like notepad++ that is it will not change existing text encoding and append new text to file

Tags: java, file, text, encoding, tortoisesvn

I am trying to append file by java program for reading file I am using scanner
`inputFile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("myfile"), "UTF-8");`
after reading enttire file I am storing it on `this.existingData=new StringBuilder(100000);` string builder and close the file`inputFile.close();`.
 for writing I am using
`outFile = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("myfile"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

i will add program generated data in this `existingData` and write it 
`outFile.print(existingData);
outFile.flush();`

and close the file
`outFile.close();`

So after that, if I try to commit the file in svn the patch file shows entire file changed instead of just newly added data. the svn diff shows only newly added change.
if I append generated data using notepad++ then in patch file only added content is displayed.

I want to make my java program to read/write a file like notpad++ that is it will not change existing text encoding and append new text to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: you always use UTF-8 for reading and writing. And the file you read may be written usng a very different encoding.

Try to determine the correct encoding using one of the libraries: [juniversalchardet](https://code.google.com/archive/p/juniversalchardet/) or [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) and write the text using the right encoding.